# jQuery .show working but not .hide when using slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, slidetoggle

I am using jQuery for multiple toggling menus on my site. However, if I change it's initial loading from .show to .hide it will not work.

My js file is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('div ul.menu').hide();
$('h2.trigger').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle('slow');
return false;
});
});
```

And my html for my multiple menus is like so:

```
<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<div>
<ul class="menu">
<li></li>
</ul>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<div>
<ul class="menu">
<li></li>
</ul>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<div>
<ul class="menu">
<li></li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

Any ideas why this will not work?

Comment: You have three open `<div>` containers.  Perhaps a typo or you didn't realize you can't leave them open.  The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) catches errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get rid of your extra `div` tag. Your `next()` is picking that instead of the ul.menu you are trying to target. Like so:

```
<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<ul class="menu">
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<ul class="menu">
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</aside>

<aside class="widget">
<h2 class="trigger">Portfolio</h2>
<ul class="menu">
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

You will also need to modify the following line

```
$('div ul.menu').hide();
```

to leave out the div

```
$('ul.menu').hide();
```

*Note: the reason that this appears to work with .show() is that your div is shown by default so the fact that the .show() is being called on the wrong item goes unnoticed.*

Comment: I typed the code in wrong, my mistake. There is supposed to be closing div's. The div's is a result of the way Wordpress generates custom menus in WP 3.0. I do not believe there is a way to remove them, but I am researching.

Comment: You were right and I found out how to remove the useless div's from Wordpress menus.